# How to remove countries from Magento 2 drop down list?

Tags: magento2, shipping, billing, drop-downs, countries

Basically I would like to show selected countries in the shipping and billing forms. Is there a correct way to achieve this?

I intend to use following JS:

```
jQuery('select[name=country_id]')
    .find('option')
    .remove()
    .end()
    .append('<option value=""> </option><option data-title="United Kingdom" value="GB">United Kingdom</option>');
```

It works fine, but I'm curious is there any other correct method available to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this from admin panel. There is no need of writing any code.

Go to Admin Panel  :

> Stores->Configuration->Sales->tax->Default Tax Destination Calculation.

There you can select whatever countries or state you want to be showed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it at checkout using a plugin and modifying the country list in $jsLayout. In my case I only use US and Canada, so:

=> In ***Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml*** you add the next

```
 <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
            <plugin name="afterProcess" type="Vendor\Module\Block\LayoutProcessor"/>
        </type>
```

=> And in ***Vendor/Module/Block/LayoutProcessor.php***:

```
     public function afterProcess(
            \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
            array $jsLayout
        )
        {
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['country_id']['options'] =
                array(
                    array(
                        'value' => '',
                        'label' => ' ',
                    ),
                    array (
                        'value' => 'CA',
                        'label' => 'Canada',
                        'is_region_required' => true,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'value' => 'US',
                        'label' => 'United States',
                        'is_region_required' => true,
                    )
                );
        return $jsLayout;
    }
```

Comment: its not working in magento 2.3

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 0):

The best method to limit the country options in Billing & Shipping is through the store configuration.

```
Store>Configuration>General>Country Options
```

Set the "Allowed Countries" to your desired options.

A full set of instructions can be found at http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/setting-billing-shipping-countries-in-magento/